# What is うろついとる？

Tags: words, contractions, subsidiary-verbs

> で、モンスターはどこら辺**うろついとるか**、わかるか？

What is うろついとる？ I'm not sure if it's a different word from うろつく or if it is short for うろついておる.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is short for うろついておる.

It is called [二重母音の融合現象](http://homepage3.nifty.com/rosetta_stone/wissenshaft/vowel_1.htm) (融合発音 synecphonesis).